# Containerizing a web application using Docker: copy source code to multiple images?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a web application XY which consists of nginx, php-fpm and mariadb. I successfully splitted everything up to it's own container using docker-compose and it's running like a charm. For development purposes I just mounted a local directory that contains the actual source/php code. When deploying this to a staging or production environment the Docker docs told me to bake the source code into the actual image. In this case I have to copy the source code to the nginx as well as to the php-fpm image when building it, because both of them need it.

When the application itself gets bigger (more assets and libaries) the nginx and php-fpm images grow both. In my opinion this somehow violates the "keep the image as small as possible" rule and this seems so deeply wrong to me. I've always learned not to repeat myself and store logic in one place, encouple things and so on.

Is this the right way to do it, or am I missing something?

Comment: The obvious thing to do is creating a volume that shares the code between the two. But this is not a solution for me, because I want to keep everything portable. :/

Comment: "Keep the image as small as possible" is good. But if you don't bake your PHP source code in to an image, how could you make sure your image is fully portable and ready to run as designed in any environment? Think about the Wordpress Docker image on Docker Hub https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/.

Comment: The WordPress docker image runs several processes in one container: webserver, interpreter, database... There's no problem baking the source code in there. I want to run only one process in one container, so the whole application consists of multiple containers. There's no real problem copying the source to the single images either, but I have to do it multiple times. nginx needs the actual code, php needs the actual code and maybe there's a worker process that needs the code too. Baking the whole source in multiple images just seems kinda wrong to me, so I asked for the best practise here.

Comment: Okay, I'm looking for the best practices also. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an interesting writeup on [Dockerise your PHP application with Nginx and PHP7-FPM](http://geekyplatypus.com/dockerise-your-php-application-with-nginx-and-php7-fpm/). This example uses volumes to share code between PHP and Nginx.

Your point about not repeating yourself isn't a bad one, but consider you may not always want the same number of Nginx containers and PHP containers. Maybe the PHP part of your application will be under more load than the part that serves static assets and you'll want to scale that up independently. If you use something like Docker Swarm, you aren't even guaranteed all of your PHP containers will be on the same host.

Your images are deployment artifacts, there isn't anything wrong with having the same static content baked into multiple images.

Answer (score 2):

In this case I'd probably create a new container which would contain the source code. This container can export the source code's directory in a volume that both the nginx and the php-fpmcan can mount.